# Android OS not respecting Network Security Config

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-network-security-config

[From the official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config), it's clear that apps that target API level 24 or later do not trust User certificate authorities (CA). Therefore adding a root CA to the user CAs in settings should not change the behavior of an app that has not overwritten the network security config.

Our *Xamarin* app has a network security config that has not added/changed the `<trust-anchors>` tag:

```
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
  </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

...and yet when we install a user CA in the OS settings, the app will trust it for the connection to the back-end services.

[image: User A]

Edit: We've used apktool to reverse-engineer the final APK and make sure that the generated manifest is still pointing to the network security config with the expected content, and indeed it does so it seems no problem there.

Is the Android documentation inaccurate?

Comment: "the app will trust it for the connection to the back-end services" -- how are you communicating to those back-end services?

Comment: var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
handler.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
var client = new HttpClient(handler)

Comment: That syntax feels Xamarin-y. Perhaps there is something about their HTTP client where they opt into honoring user certificates.

Comment: It is indeed Xamarin, I should've mentioned that and was suspicious of the same possibility. So I took apktool and inspected the final package to see if they had modified the manifest or network security config but the final manifest was still pointing to the same network security config, so that's intact.